# Remove specific roles from delimited list of users (Discord/Python)

Tags: python, list, discord, delimited

I'm trying to make a little bot that will remove specific roles from a list of users I specify. I have all of the id's and usernames of the users I need to remove roles from, but I don't know how to code it to allow for a long delimited list as a variable. My intended usage is something like

```
-strip (userid1,userid2,userid3)
```

...capable of a dynamic list that will vary in the number of members included.

Here's my use case for more context - I have a Patreon which grants roles to my Discord. However, Patreon can only give roles, not remove them. I've made a scraper that will compare a list of patrons to a list of discord members and their roles. It filters out a list of canceled patrons that still have Discord roles. I want to just be able to pop that list into a bot command and have it wipe the roles.

The script below currently allows me to remove specific roles from a single user. It's working fine, but need a way to allow for a list of users as opposed to a single user.

Thanks in advance!

```
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import discord

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '-', help_command=None)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'{client.user} has awakened!')
    
@client.command()
async def swipe(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    role_names = ("role1", "role2", "role3")
    roles = tuple(get(ctx.guild.roles, name=n) for n in role_names)
    await user.remove_roles(*roles)
    await ctx.send(f'Removed **all** Patreon roles from {user.mention}.')

my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']
client.run(my_secret)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like so:

```
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import discord

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '-', help_command=None)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'{client.user} has awakened!')
    
async def helper(ctx, user_id):
    role_names = ("role1", "role2", "role3")
    roles = tuple(get(ctx.guild.roles, name=n) for n in role_names)
    user = await ctx.guild.fetch_member(int(user_id)) #notice the additional line here
    await user.remove_roles(*roles)
    await ctx.send(f'Removed **all** Patreon roles from {user.mention}.')

@client.command()
async def swipe(ctx, *args):
    for user in args:
        await helper(ctx, int(user))


my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']
client.run(my_secret)
```

Now `swipe` takes args like: `-swipe user1 user2 user3` and calls your original function (now called `helper`) for each user.

Comment: Errored due to no 'async' in front of 'def'. I added it, then got this error when attempting to use: main.py:21: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'helper' was never awaited
  helper(ctx, user)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback. In case it matters, I was using user id which is a number 18 characters long.

Comment: @user3108489 You may have to write `await helper(ctx, user)` instead of `helper(ctx, user)` now that you have `async`.

Comment: Added 'await' and got this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/ExPat/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 21, in swipe
    await helper(ctx, user)
  File "main.py", line 15, in helper
    await user.remove_roles(*roles)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'

Comment: @user3108489 apologies, you will need to add `user = client.get_user(user_id)` since you send a string to helper. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this. Similar error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  ne 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/ExPat/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/ExPat/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'

Comment: Here's how I'm attempting to use it:  -swipe 285345800839434240 192678921985867776

Comment: Also testing with a single arg, but same error

Comment: if `user = client.get_user(user_id)` is returning None type then maybe you have the id wrong?

Comment: `get_user` returns none when it cannot find the id.

Comment: Wait a minute, i think we have to make id an `int`. so `await helper(ctx, int(user))` not `await helper(ctx, user)`. I updated my answer, give that a shot.

Comment: actually `fetch_member` should be better, updated again.

Comment: New error:  ... line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 22, in swipe
    await helper(ctx, int(user))
  File "main.py", line 16, in helper
    await user.remove_roles(*roles)
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'

AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Guild.fetch_member' was never awaited
  self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: @user3108489 lol try it again, I forget the `await` I updated it now.

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you! Marked your answer as correct.

Comment: @user3108489 you're welcome!